# Validate data from form

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate each element of my html form.

That's my code:

```
function check()
{
    var re1 = new RegExp("^[a-zA-z]{3,20}$"); //Prename
    var re2 = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$"); //Username
    var index;
    var element;
    var data = ["prename", "lastname", "username", "email", "password", "password1"];

    for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index)
    {
        element = data[i];
        checkinput(element);
    }

}   

function checkinput(element)
{
    if (element == "prename")
    {
        if (document.register.element.value.match(re1))
        {
            document.getElementById(element).style.borderColor="lightgreen";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(element).style.borderColor="red";
        }
    }
    else if (element == "lastname")
    {
        if (document.register.element.value.match(re1))
        {
            document.getElementById(element).style.borderColor="lightgreen";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(element).style.borderColor="red";
        }
    }
    else if (element == "username")
    {
        if (document.register.element.value.match(re2))
        {
            document.getElementById(element).style.borderColor="lightgreen";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(element).style.borderColor="red";
        }
    }


}
```

For example, if the input field with id `#prename` is not like my regex pattern, it should have a red border color. But its not red or green. Where is my fault?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of this?

Comment: You also don't need those return values unless you intend to refer to checkinput elsewhere.

Comment: I can't get jsfiddle working. But you can test it here: http://new.infinity-hosting.ch/register.php
@elreimundo You're right. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an event listener on the page that is running check() ? You might consider adding `document.addEventListener('keypress',check)` to your js file to make sure that check is actually executing where you want it to.

It might make more sense to have the listener just on the elements you care about; that is, you'll run the check on the specific fields you want to check. This would result in code that's along the lines of:

```
regExChecker = {
  prename: new RegExp("^[a-zA-z]{3,20}$"),
  lastname: new RegExp("^[a-zA-z]{3,20}$"),
  username: new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$")
}

function checkElement(evt) {
  var el = evt.target
  if (el.value.match(regExChecker[el.id])){
    el.style.borderColor = "lightgreen";
  }
  else {
    el.style.borderColor = "red";
  }
}

function bindListeners(){
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(arguments[i]).addEventListener('keypress',checkElement)
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  bindListeners('prename', 'lastname', 'username')
}
```

Comment: Before I added the loop and the new function "checkinput", it worked well. But I have added the event listener on the first line now.

Comment: Updated suggestion above. Mine works on your page, though it handles backspaces differently than other keys.

Comment: I have problems implementing your code. What am I doing wrong?
For example, can I call it with `checkElement("prename");` ?
My javascript knowledge is not good :/